# How to exit a Perl program as soon as the "Wide character in print at X line Y" message appears?

Tags: perl, unicode

I have a Perl program that's giving me the following output:

```
Wide character in print at foo.pl line 139, <FILE> line 1.
Wide character in print at foo.pl line 139, <FILE> line 2.
Wide character in print at foo.pl line 139, <FILE> line 3.
```

As I don't want to add the `:utf8` layer, and I don't want to turn off the warnings either, I'm looking for a way to terminate the program and exit with an error code if a message like the above appears.

As the `print` statement is the one throwing the error, I tried to use `or die` next to the `print` statement, but that didn't help. e.g.>

```
print OUTPUT $_."\n" or die "Something wrong happened - $!";
```

I guess that's not working because `print` is not really failing - it's just displaying a message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
use warnings FATAL => 'utf8';
```

Which will cause any "Wide character" warning to be fatal, and cause the Perl process to die.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature 'say';

for (1 .. 3) {
    say "παν γράμμα";
}

say "=" x 80;

use warnings FATAL => 'utf8';

for (1 .. 3) {
    say "παν γράμμα";
}
```

Outputs:

```
alex@kyon:~$ ./fatal_wide.pl
Wide character in say at ./fatal_wide.pl line 9.
παν γράμμα
Wide character in say at ./fatal_wide.pl line 9.
παν γράμμα
Wide character in say at ./fatal_wide.pl line 9.
παν γράμμα
================================================================================
Wide character in say at ./fatal_wide.pl line 17.
```

And exits with a non-zero exit status:

```
alex@kyon:~$ echo $?
255
```

Comment: Simple demo that doesn't use `use utf8;`: `perl -E'say chr(0x2660); say "done"'` vs `perl -E'use warnings FATAL => "utf8"; say chr(0x2660); say "done"'`

Comment: Nice. We always use chr(0x2665) in our tests ;)

Comment: All answers were great, but yours is the best one.  Just to make it even greater, is there a way to set the *error number* to a value defined by the user?  For example, let's suppose that I wanted this error to be `Error 17`.

Comment: In this case I would use [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny) or similar to catch the exception and then act on it... like: `use Try::Tiny; try { print ... } catch { m/Wide/ && exit 17; };` or so.

Answer (score 2):

You need capture Perl warnings like that:

```
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    my $mes = shift;
    die $mes;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a custom [`warn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) handler then `die` if the message matches:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    my $msg = shift;
    die $msg if (index $msg, "Wide character in print") > -1;
    warn $msg;
};

warn "test warn";
print "鸡\n";
warn "won't reach";
```

Produces:

```
test warn at foo.pl line 17.
Wide character in print at foo.pl line 18.
```